# usage of states in salt runner

Tags: python, salt-stack

I'm trying to write my own salt runner in python which does a clone of a git repository, parses data in some and provide a roster file.

I'm now stucked by using a salt state like 
okay what i got till now is.

```
def a_runner():
    gittarget='/var/tmp/some-repository'
    remote_url= 'ssh://git@some-repostitory'
    result = __salt__['state.single']('git.latest', name=remote_url, branch='master', target=gittarget, force_checkout=True, force_reset=True)
```

if i run this runner i got this error

```
    Exception occurred in runner test.a_runner: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/client/mixins.py", line 382, in _low
        data['return'] = self.functions[fun](*args, **kwargs)
      File "/srv/salt/_runners/test.py", line 11, in a_runner
        result = __salt__['state.single']('git.latest',
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1114, in __getitem__
        func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 101, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'state.single'
```

I found a solution for my problem. not the best one but it worked for me

```
def a_runner():

    client = salt.client.LocalClient(__opts__['conf_file'])
    gittarget='/var/tmp/some-repository'
    remote_url= 'ssh://git@some-repostitory'

    try:
        clone_success = __salt__['salt.cmd'](fun='git.clone', cwd=gittarget, url=remote_url)

    except Exception as exc:
        log.error(
            'Exception \'%s\' caught while cloning git repository '
            'remote \'%s\'', str(exc), remote_url,
            exc_info_on_loglevel=logging.DEBUG
        )
```

Comment: I bet the error is on line 23.

Comment: Can you provide code that you are using to do this?